# Is there a differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$ that satisfies $y'=y^n$ and $y(0)>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $n$ be an integer greater than $1$. Is there a differentiable function on $[0,\infty)$ that satisfies $y'=y^n$ and $y(0)>0$?

My attempt: We solve the differential equation noting that

$\frac{dy}{dt}=y^n$

$\int\frac{1}{y^n}=\int dt$

So we get that $y=((1-n)(t+c))^{\frac{1}{1-n}}$ for some constant $c$.

However, I notice that since $n\geq2$, we get that

$y(0)=((1-n)c)^{\frac{1}{1-n}}$, so $c$ must be negative in order to actually evaluate this term. In this case, my answer is yes, there exists a function, but I'm not sure this is correct.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Seeing that $c$ is negative, $-c$ must be in $[0,+\infty[$. What is $y(-c)$?

Comment: @GitGud $y(-c)=0$, which is a problem because $y(0)>0$, so there must be some point in $[0,\infty)$ such that $y'<0$, so $y^n<0$, but by our definition of $y$, it can never be negative. Is that correct?

Comment: No. There's no reason *a priori* (that I see) for $y$ not to be allowed to be negative sometimes. Rather, $y(-c)=0^{\frac{1}{1-n}}$. What is, for instance, $0^{-\frac 1 7}$?

Comment: @GitGud Ah, right--I should have noticed that we're dividing by zero. Thanks!

Comment: No problem!${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the main point: whatever positive number is picked for $y(0),$ the solution of the ODE $y' = y^n$ blows up in finite time.

If $n=2$ and $y(0) = \frac{1}{W} $ with constant $W > 0,$ then
$$ y(x) = \frac{1}{W - x}  $$
for $x < W.$ The solution does not extend to $+\infty$ as requested.

If $n=3$ and $y(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2W}} $ with constant $W > 0,$ then
$$ y(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2W - 2x}}  $$
for $x < W.$ The solution does not extend to $+\infty$ as requested.